# Extracting data from Eclipse's JDT visitor pattern

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt, visitor-pattern

So I'm playing around with Eclipse's JDT API and trying to build a small app. However, I'm stuck when extracting data from the visited nodes since I can only print them.

I'd like to be able to, for example, return or add the value of getSuperclassType() to a List or HashMap. However, since the new ASTVisitor is an inner class, Java does not allow me to declare an Object used inside the ASTVisitor without the final keyword.

```
private static void get(String src) {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(src.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);

    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        Set names = new HashSet();

        public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration typeDecNode) {
            if(!typeDecNode.isInterface()) {
                System.out.println(typeDecNode.getName().toString());
                System.out.println(typeDecNode.getSuperclassType());
                System.out.println(typeDecNode.superInterfaceTypes().toString());

                return true;
            }
...
```

Is it possible from a piece of code like this to store the desired data from each visited node into a data structure? Or maybe another way to traverse the nodes from the AST without using the visitor pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a normal class extending `ASTVisitor` as the visitor instead of the anonymous class you are currently using and store whatever you like in the class.

For example for the super types something like:

```
class MyVisitor extends ASTVisitor
{
  private List<Type> superTypes = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration typeDecNode) {
       if(!typeDecNode.isInterface()) {
            superTypes.add(typeDecNode.getSuperclassType());
            return true;
       }
  }

  List<Type> getSuperTypes() {
     return superTypes;
  }
}
```

and use with:

```
MyVisitor myVisitor = new MyVisitor();

cu.accept(myVisitor);

List<Type> superTypes = myVisitor.getSuperTypes();
```

Alternatively you can access a `final` list in an anonymous class like this:

```
final List<Type> superTypes = new ArrayList<>();

cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
     public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration typeDecNode) {
        if(!typeDecNode.isInterface()) {
            superTypes.add(typeDecNode.getSuperclassType());

            return true;
        }
```